# I'm trying in pandas to get the n'th value of space by splitting the column value with delimiter

Tags: python, pandas

I creatated a dataframe `df` with csv data looking like:

```
col_1,col_2
001,JOHN VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL^RANDY VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL^MICHAEL VARCHAR(105) NOT NULL^DATE STRING
002,Danny VARCHAR(87)^EDWARD VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL^ROB VARCHAR(73) NOT NULL
```

I'm trying to get the second value of space delimiter by splitting `col_2` by ^ delimiter like below df

```
col_1,col_2,col_3
001,JOHN VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL^RANDY VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL^MICHAEL VARCHAR(105) NOT NULL^DATE STRING,VARCHAR(11)^VARCHAR(2)^VARCHAR(105)^STRING
002,Danny VARCHAR(87)^EDWARD VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL^ROB VARCHAR(73) NOT NULL,VARCHAR(87)^VARCHAR(4)^VARCHAR(73)
```

I'm using below but unable to get the 2nd value of space

```
df['col_3'] = df['col_2'].map(lambda v: v.split(' ')[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it might not answer your question directly, but i think the question should be related to how to explode a list inside a pandas dataframe.

```
df["col_2"].str.split("^", expand=True).stack().reset_index()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right path, you can split the value of `col2` using the `^` character and get the data types joined by `^` and assign it to `col3` as such:

```py
import pandas as pd

data = {'col1':['001','002'],
        'col2': ['JOHN VARCHAR(11) NOT NULL^RANDY VARCHAR(2) NOT NULL^MICHAEL VARCHAR(105) NOT NULL^DATE STRING',
                 'Danny VARCHAR(87)^EDWARD VARCHAR(4) NOT NULL^ROB VARCHAR(73) NOT NULL']}
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)

df['col3'] = list(map(lambda x: '^'.join([col.split(' ')[1] for col in x]), df.col2.str.split('^')) )
```

Results

```py
0    VARCHAR(11)^VARCHAR(2)^VARCHAR(105)^STRING
1            VARCHAR(87)^VARCHAR(4)^VARCHAR(73)
Name: col3, dtype: object
```